# Python Regex to extract file where filename contains and also should not contain specific pattern from a zip folder

Tags: python, regex, zip, python-re, python-zipfile

I want to extract just one specific single file from the zip folder which has the below 3 files.
***Basically it should start with 'kpidata_nfile' and should not contain 'fileheader'***

**kpidata_nfile_20220919-20220925_fileheader.csv

kpidata_nfile_20220905-20220911.csv

othername_kpidata_nfile_20220905-20220911.csv**

Below is my code i have tried-

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import re
import os
for x in os.listdir('.'):
  if re.match('.*\.(zip)', x):
      with ZipFile(x, 'r') as zip:
          for info in zip.infolist():
              if re.match(r'^kpidata_nfile_', info.filename):
                  zip.extract(info)
```

**Output required - kpidata_nfile_20220905-20220911.csv**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex does what you require:

```
^kpidata_nfile(?:(?!fileheader).)*$
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) for more about the `(?:(?!fileheader).)*$` part.

You can see the regex working on your example filenames [here](https://regex101.com/r/jK43OD/1).

The regex is not particularly readable, so it might be better to use Python expressions instead of regex. Something like:

```
fname = info.filename
if fname.startswith('kpidata_nfile') and 'fileheader' not in fname:
```

Comment: Cool, perfect! regex worked and the python expression is very useful, thank you